# No Xbox Live Gold, want multiplayer FPS and racing games (XBox One)

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

As per title, I have inherited an XBox One.

Do I have to shell out for xbox live gold in order to play online or are there any half-decent FP shooters or racing games (eg Call Of Duty / Forza) that work without it?

Latest & greatest not required - please specify versions!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you [cannot play multiplayer games](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/what-happens-when-you-lose-xbox-live-gold-on-xbox-one) without a Xbox Live Gold membership. You will also lose access to games you've acquired with the monthly "Games with Gold" giveaways. Most apps and local split-screen and offline singleplayer games will continue to work.

One of the workarounds to using the multiplayer features of the Xbox One without paying for Xbox Live is to [use someone else's account](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-play-multiplayer-without-having-Xbox-Live-Gold) who already has Xbox Live. You cannot both use the same account simultaneously, of course, but it does allow you to play games online if you have a friend who can loan you an account.

User Ryan_L also [mentions three alternate workarounds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/362447/228910) in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to the best of my knowledge you cannot play online via Xbox live without Xbox live gold.  I remember way back in the original Xbox days, people used to use virtual LANs to play online without Xbox live gold, much the same how PC users do with Game Ranger or Hamachi.  Nowadays though, games don't generally support LAN play and those that do have a ping limit specifically to prevent this kind of thing.  It might be worth a shot if you have a few friends within a few hundred miles.  Just don't expect server browsers and matchmaking.

But you don't necessarily have to pay for a gold account.  Microsoft offers a bunch of different ways to "earn" free gold account time.  For instance, if you use Bing, each search you do accrues points, and 7000 points can buy one month of Xbox live gold.  There's also a bunch of ways to get free trial accounts, but they're only good for a month and last time I tried it you had to make a new account for every trial.